# number of subarrays whose product is even?

Tags: c++, arrays, sub-array

given an array of size n, n<=10^5 what is efficient approach to count number of sub arrays whose product is even  ?
i am using naive approach with (On^3) time complexity ?
please suggest some efficient approach?

Comment: Show the naive approach that you have. I feel like worst case complexity is O(n^3), but everyone just hit the subarray problems in their CS classes for this semester so I'm also just learning it for the first time.

Comment: If you have at least one even number in the sub array, the product becomes even. You can check the number of even elements in O(n) time. The rest is just combinatorics and should be doable in O(1). It's been too long since I dealt with any maths, so I can't provide the formula - I suppose it's just number of all combinations minus number of combinations without even number (however that would be calculated). You may try to ask on [math.se], but please read their [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help pages](https://math.stackexchange.com/help) - I'm not a regular there.

Comment: You just need to find the number of sub-arrays that contain at least one even value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful: from your explanation I have the impression that you are taking all sub-arrays, calculate the product and check if it is even.

However there's one very important mathematical rule: when you have a series of natural numbers, as soon as there's one even number, the product will be even.

So, I'd advise you to program following algorithm:

1. Search in your array for an even number.
2. Count the amount of sub-arrays, containing that even number.
3. Search in your array for the next even number.
4. Count the amount of sub-arrays, containing that next even number, but not containing the previous even number.
5. Continue until you've processed all even numbers in your array.